# EasyMock to test exceptions

Tags: dao, easymock

I am trying to test with EasyMock the service layer by mocking the DAO. 
One of the methods in my DAO class is shown below.

```
public BrickStreamUserVO getUserDetails(String userName, String password) 
{
BrickStreamUserVO usrObj = null;

try
{
    String sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM USER_T WHERE USER_NAME LIKE '" + userName + "'
    AND PASSWORD = '" + password + "'";
    usrObj = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sqlStr, new BrickStreamUserMapper());

    logger.info("Getting user details....");

    if(usrObj==null)
    throw new UserException("Invalid Login parameters");
} 
catch (Exception e)
{   
    logger.error(e);        
    throw new UserException("Invalid Login parameters");
}

return usrObj;
}
```

And here is my test code

```
public class BrickStreamServiceImplTest
{
private BrickStreamServiceImpl serviceImpl;

@Before
public void buildService()
{
serviceImpl = new BrickStreamServiceImpl(); 
}

@Test
public void testGetUserDetails()
{   

BrickStreamDaoImpl daoImplMock = createMock(BrickStreamDaoImpl.class);  
expect(daoImplMock.getUserDetails("user", "pwd")).
        andReturn(new BrickStreamUserVO()); 
replay(daoImplMock);

serviceImpl.setBrickStreamDao(daoImplMock);
serviceImpl.getUserDetails("user", "pwd");

verify(daoImplMock);


    }
}
```

How can I test the method to throw the UserException, you can see that if the usrObj object is null it throws a UserException.

Answer (score 1):

If you mock the `getUserDetails` method, you won't be able to test its behavior.

You may want to extract a method where you do the user query, and mock it.

```
public BrickStreamUserVO queryForUser(String userName, String password) { 
    String sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM USER_T WHERE USER_NAME LIKE '" + userName + "'
    AND PASSWORD = '" + password + "'";
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sqlStr, new BrickStreamUserMapper());
}

public BrickStreamUserVO getUserDetails(String userName, String password) 
{
    BrickStreamUserVO usrObj = null;

    try
    {
        usrObj = queryForUser(userName, password);
        logger.info("Getting user details....");

        if(usrObj==null) {
            throw new UserException("Invalid Login parameters");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {   
       logger.error(e);        
       throw new UserException("Invalid Login parameters");
    }

    return usrObj;
}
```

In your test class :

```
@Test(expected = UserException.class)
public void testGetUserDetails()
{   
    BrickStreamDaoImpl daoImplMock = createMockBuilder(BrickStreamDaoImpl.class).addMockedMethod("queryForUser").createMock();  
    expect(daoImplMock.queryForUser("user", "pwd")).andReturn(null); 
    replay(daoImplMock);

    serviceImpl.setBrickStreamDao(daoImplMock);
    serviceImpl.getUserDetails("user", "pwd");
}
```

Comment: It does serve the purpose but then it is duplicating the method. I have to do this with all the methods in my DAO. Is something wrong with my DAO design.

Comment: I tend not to test Dao methods as they are only Data providers, and have too few algorithms.
I prefer to test methods with business value calling my Dao. I then mock the Dao methods.

Comment: All my DAO's are pretty much the same as this one, I am testing the service layer here by mocking the DAO. Your solution is right to achieve what I wanted but I think that part of it could be tested at DAO level.

Comment: @SamyAmirou when handling the method that normally needs a try/catch or throws added, do you need to do anything for java to not yell at this syntactically?  I have a similar problem, but I keep needing to add a try catch around what I'm "expecting" to throw an error and I am not sure how to handle that.